# Magento group prices

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

im creating a magento store for a B2B store.
The issue im facing is that i need to have a different price for a different customer group.
i have checked the built in group price feature in Magento but this is not what i need since it just shows a price for the specific groupo only when it is  LOWER than the actual price and it shows it as a SPECIAL PRICE in the front end 
What i need is to have a different price for each customer group without showing it as a SPECIAL PRICE is that possible ?
if yes how could i do that ? do i change some PHP code ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento will always display the minimal price between actual price, special price, group price and the catalog price rule.

Comment: how could i overcome this ? any ideas ?